# APP Crash : Fatal Exception: io.reactivex.exceptions.CompositeException

Tags: android, retrofit2, reactivex

Using `retrofit` I call `API` for getting list, but when no data found then I am calling `onErrorGetOccasion` method and in that I got `HttpException` and for that I handle it as shown in code.

Now my issue is sometimes in `onErrorGetOccasion` method I got Fatal

```
Exception: io.reactivex.exceptions.CompositeException this error and app crash.
```

Any suggestion for this?

```
//Get Occasion API
private void callGetOccasionAPI(String pageIndex, boolean isDialogShown) {

    if (NetworkUtils.isConnected()) {
        if (mPageCount == 1 && isDialogShown)
            showProgressDialog(mContext);
        RetrofitAdapter.createRetroServiceWithSessionToken(mContext)
                .getOccasion(pageIndex)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(this::onSuccessGetOccasion, this::onErrorGetOccasion);
    } else {
        SnackBarUtils.defaultSnackBar(getString(R.string.error_no_internet), mRootView);
    }
}

private void onErrorGetOccasion(Throwable throwable) {
    hideProgressDialog();
    if (throwable instanceof HttpException) {
        ResponseBody body = ((HttpException) throwable).response().errorBody();
        Utils.setLog(body != null ? body.toString() : null);
        try {
            if (body != null) {
                if (body.string().contains(mContext.getString(R.string.msg_event_not_found))) {
                    if (mPageCount == 1) {
                        mTxtRecordNotFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                } else {
                    SnackBarUtils.errorSnackBar(getString(R.string.error_api), mRootView, null);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Crashlytics.log(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`CompositeException` is usually thrown when your error handler itself throws an exception when it's handling an error thrown in the stream.

Make sure your error handling code is not throwing any exceptions.

Usually the stack trace will have the root cause below the `CompositeException`, prefixed with `Caused by`.

Comment: How to handle it?

Comment: You need to see what the underlying exception is, if it's something that needs to be fixed, like NullPointerException for example or something to be caught, IOException, posting your full stack trace will help as well.